# Does a docker container need to be a web server for a fargate task definition to specify a Health Check Command?

Tags: windows, docker, aws-fargate

**Context**

- I have created a docker container and pushed that to an ecr repo.
- The docker container runs a python script that will process items from an sqs queue and then upload results to an s3 bucket
- I am using fargate to run this windows docker container as a fargate service.
- In the task definition for the fargate service, I want to define a health check, but I am unsure what to do for my situation

**Question**

1. In most of the examples that I have seen, health check definitions curl localhost at some port.  I don't have a ton of experience in this area so I am unsure if I need to make my docker container be a web server? Do I need to add flask or something so that my python application responds to http requests?
2. For applications like mine which are retrieving queue items, processing those items, and uploading s3, what would be the best way to check the health of that container?  I have seen examples where a script is used, but within that script I am not sure what would be best to check.

If you have any resources or insights to share, I would really appreciate your input!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Putting the specific technology aside: if you ran your program in one window, above and beyond "it hasn't exited", how would you check to see if it's still doing work?

Comment: in this situation I would check to see if the queue items were getting consumed or if the dead letter queue was getting populated & I would also check that for each queue item processed, there was an s3 upload.  I guess I am wondering if there is best practice for docker health checks for non-webserver based docker containers